# MVC and SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have right clicked on App_Data and added a new SQL Server Compact Local Database. I have created a table called Customer with one field for now - Name.

In which part of the MVC Application, i.e. Controller, Model or View do I send data to the SQL Server and how do I actually send the data itself? How do I connect to the newly made Database?

I have called the Database MyDB.sdf

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? If so, what is your approach - code first (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) or something else? I would recommend checking out the tutorial I linked to in order to better understand how the database works with an ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the App.config file to specify the database name using connectionString. This connected to my SQL Server Database which was created in SQL Server Management Studio.